# How do you use node's method-override package with ajax to override methods to put?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, overriding

I am new to web development, so forgive me if the following may be unclear... Please let me know if any clarification is needed... I am also new to stackoverflow, so try to take it easy on me :P

My question is, how does one use node's "method-override" package with ajax?
I need to override a POST method and set it as a PUT method... for user registration and login forms for a school assignment...
The documentation is not very helpful, as it shows no examples of how to use method-override with ajax...
Also, probably not that it matters... but I am using a non-relational db to store user info (mongodb)... I am also using node's "cookie-session" package, but for the purpose of this question, I will omit the cookie-session stuff...

So far,  in my user route, I have:

```js
const express = require('express');
const userRoutes = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

userRoutes.use(methodOverride('_method'));

userRoutes.put('/', (req, res) => {
  // ... user registration logic here
})

userRoutes.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // ... user login logic here
})
```

---

for my client-side, I have:

```js
$(() => {
  let $registrationInfo = $('.registration form');
  let $loginInfo = $('.login form');

  $.ajax({
      method: POST,
      url: '/users',
      data: $registrationInfo.serialize();
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --HELP!!!
    })
    .then((new_user) => {
      // ... client side user registration logic here
      console.log('new user created');
    })

  $.ajax({
      method: POST,
      url: '/users',
      data: $loginInfo.serialize();
    })
    .then((user_login) => {
      // ... client side user login logic here
      console.log('user has logged in');
    })
})
```

---

for my html, I have:

```html
<div class="registration">
  <form method="POST" action="/users/">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="submit" class="register" name="register" value="Register" />
      </li>
    </ol>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="login">
  <form method="POST" action="/users/">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="submit" class="login" name="login" value="Login" />
      </li>
    </ol>
  </form>
</div>
```

not sure how to implement "_method"... please help!

THANKS IN ADV.!

edit: P.S. we are required to use the above middleware for this project, and are supposed to use as little html as possible...

Answer (score 0):

As described in the method-override package [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#override-using-a-query-value)

> To use a query string value to override the method, specify the query
>   string key as a string argument to the methodOverride function. To
>   then make the call, send a POST request to a URL with the overridden
>   method as the value of that query string key. This method of using a
>   query value would typically be used in conjunction with plain HTML
>    elements when trying to support legacy browsers but still use
>   newer methods.

You have specified the query string as `_method`, so if you want to override the http method to PUT you include the query sting `_method=PUT`.

```
<form method="POST" action="/users?_method=PUT">
 ...
</form>
```

To parse the forms on the server side you should use the body-parser on the users routes.

```
userRoutes.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```